# Pasar valor de id seleccionado en dropdowlist al controlador para filtrar webgrid

Tags: mvc, dropdownlist

Anteriormente había hecho una pregunta que gracias a Davlio ya se resolvió.

---

Sin embargo me surgió otra duda, tengo dos procedimientos almacenados mapeados en entityframework, uno para llenar el `dropdownlist` (GetDepartamentos_Result) y otro para llenar un `webgrid` dependiendo de la selección que haga en el dropdownlist(SearchEmployeesDropDown_Result).

---

La cuestion es que por lo que he leido no se pueden tener dos modelos en una vista por lo que hice un nuevo modelo que contegan mis dos modelos de mis stored procedure quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
   namespace WebgridPagingSortingFiltering.Models
     {
          public class ViewModels
             {
               public List<GetDepartamentos_Result> Combo { get; set; }
                 public List<SearchEmployeesDropDown_Result> Grid { get; set; }
                  public int SelectedDeparmentID { get; set; }
              }
         }
```

agregue una nueva propiedad `SelectedDeparmentID` para el valor del Id del `dropdownlist`.

En mi controlador tengo lo siguiente dos métodos uno para llenar el `dropdownlist` y otro para poblar el `wegrid`:

Para llenar el `drop`:

```
  public List<GetDepartamentos_Result> GetDepartamentos()
        {
            using (TigerEntities db = new TigerEntities())
           {
               ViewModels vm = new ViewModels();
               vm.Combo = db.GetDepartamentos().ToList();
               return vm.Combo;
           }
        }
```

Para llenar el `webgrid`:

```
 public List<SearchEmployeesDropDown_Result> GetEmpleadosbyDrop (int Id_dep)
       {
           using (TigerEntities db = new TigerEntities())
          {
               ViewModels vm = new ViewModels();
               vm.Grid = db.SearchEmployeesDropDown(Id_dep).ToList();
               return vm.Grid;
           }
        }
```

Y tengo un metodo actionresult que me carga los datos en la vista para el `dropdownlist`:

```
 public ActionResult Combo()
       {
        var a = GetDepartamentos();
        ViewBag.Departamentos = new SelectList(a, "Id_Departamento", 
        "Nombre_Departamento");
        return View(b);
       }
```

En mi vista tengo lo siguiente:

```
   @model WebgridPagingSortingFiltering.Models.ViewModels

   @{
      Layout = null;
      var grid = new WebGrid(canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 4);
      grid.Bind(source: Model.Grid, rowCount: ViewBag.TotalRows);
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm("combo", "home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = 
    "navbar-form navbar-left" }))
                {
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => 
      model.SelectedDeparmentID, ViewBag.Departamentos as SelectList, new { 
     @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-
     success">Search</button>
                }
```

Mi duda es como paso el valor del id del dropdownlist al controlador para que haga el filtrado con el stored procedure que he hecho y me muestre los datos en el webgrid.

Tengo el mismo metodo actionresult pero no se que pasarle como parametro:

```
 [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult Combo(??) No se si pasarle el modelo ViewModels o 
     el SelectedDeparmentID
     {
        var a = GetDepartamentos();
        ViewBag.Departamentos = new SelectList(a, "Id_Departamento", 
            "Nombre_Departamento");
        var b = GetEmpleadosbyDrop(??);
        return View(b);
      }
```

Agradeceria mucho su ayuda que me puedan proporcionar. 
Saludos